# Is there a limit to the quantity of text one can write in Stickies?

Tags: text-editor, stickies

I've gotten into the (bad) habit of writing for hours within **Stickies**. It's fast to start up, uses very little RAM, doesn't distract me with bells and whistles or obtrusive GUI, it auto-saves, and the windows can be usually very small, which I like.

Some of my notes are becoming rather large, however, and I am wondering if there's a limit to the quantity of text one can write in Stickies (with the default font and font size). Or if the limit may be assigned to the overall quantity of text within all Stickies notes combined.

Comment: How large is the stickies DB in question? Use Finder to open the folder ~/Library/ It's named StickiesDatabase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be. The only issue you may incur is writing too much for your RAM to handle, but that's into if you write gigabytes unto gigibytes of raw text. 
The average user shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a source for that? I'd rather be sure

Comment: @MicroMachine just general RAM limits. Stickies is a simple text editor and should be just as functional as that. Just like in notepad for Windows, you can type as much as you want until your computer crashes when you run out of ram.

Answer (score 0):

The database will surely struggle before you hit an architectural limit since HFS + lets a file grow to 8 Exabytes.

I would perform a little profiling to see what is making your app slow if you find things problematic down the road.

1. Turn off any apps that start when you log in to the Mac (System Preferences - search for log in items)
2. Restart your Mac and log in.
3. Open Activity Monitor (Applications/Utilities folder) - look at memory usage and CPU usage. Wait for it to level off and then open the stickies app.
4. See how that app increases CPU and/or memory.

Once you know what the isolated load of that app is, then repeat the test with all the apps you need to run in addition to stickies. It's likely you have some other bottleneck, but it's easy to make sure.

Comment: There might have been a misunderstanding, I never said anything was slow, just that there was a lot of text inside the notes.

Comment: Problem solved then. No slow, load it up more ;-) @MicroMachine (on a technical level, it's a NSMutableArray so the storage of the database should scale to reasonable values of what someone might be able to show on one screen. I've seen thousands of notes collapsed and organized like a glorious multi-colored checkerboard to no ill effect.